# Laravel Seeder for Different Environments

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, seed

I created two folders in my seeder folder:

```
/seeds
    /local
    /production
    DatabaseSeeder.php
```

Then, defined the following inside `DatabaseSeeder.php`

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

```
/**
 * Run the database seeds.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function run()
{
    Eloquent::unguard();

    // Load production seeder
    if (App::Environment() === 'production')
    {
        $this->call('production/UsersTableSeeder');
    }

    // Load local seeder
    if (App::Environment() === 'local')
    {
        $this->call('local/UsersTableSeeder');
    }
}
```

}

Now I know I can't do `call('local/UsersTablderSeeder')`, and that is my question. How can I `call()` the seeder files from their respective folders?

**Edit**

To be clear, when I run the code as it is shown above, I get the following error

```
[ReflectionException]                            
Class local/UsersTableSeeder does not exist
```

Comment: I dont understand your question - what is wrong with what you have written?

Comment: Please see above, the file is not found

Comment: Have you tried namespacing each `UsersTableSeeder`. That way you could `call('local\UsersTableSeeder');` . The call method is looking for a class, not a file.

Comment: I namespaced each `UsersTableSeeder` as `namespace seeds\local`, and then called it via `call('seeds\local\UsersTableSeeder')` and that also didn't work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just tried this quickly and got it working, so I'll show you how I set it up and hopefully that helps.

app/database/seeds/local/UsersTableSeeder.php

```
<?php namespace Seeds\Local;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder as Seeder;

Class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder {
    public function run () {
        dd('local');
    }
}
```

app/database/seeds/production/UsersTableSeeder.php

```
<?php namespace Seeds\Production;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder as Seeder;

Class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder {
    public function run () {
        dd('production');
    }
}
```

app/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php

```
<?php

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run(){
        Eloquent::unguard();

        // Load production seeder
        if (App::Environment() === 'production')
        {
            $this->call('Seeds\Production\UsersTableSeeder');
        }

        // Load local seeder
        if (App::Environment() === 'local')
        {
            $this->call('Seeds\Local\UsersTableSeeder');
        }
    }

}
```

And don't forget to run composer dump-autoload.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

Laravel 5.7 or higher

```
if ( App::environment('local') ) {
        $this->call(Seeder::class);
}
if ( App::environment('production') ) {
            $this->call(Seeder::class);
}
if ( App::environment('testing') ) {
            $this->call(Seeder::class);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `'/'`. You should use `'\'` instead.